# Displaying variable results in html elements - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

With my code below, i cannot reach the html `$(this).find(".total span")` and `line-total` which is affecting my calculation.

When i alert my variables, the results are accurate but then the i cannot reach the `$(this).find(".total span")` and `line-total` to display the results.

How can i reach the `$(this).find(".total span")` and `line-total` please?

```
  function source(product)
        { 
          var item = JSON.parse(product.dataset.product), checker ;
          if(product.checked == true)  {

            checker = $('.panel_input[data-id="' + item.id + '"]');

        if (checker.length) { checker.closest('.container').find('.quantity').val(function(i, value) {

           quantity = parseInt(value, 10) + 1;
           price = Number($(this).closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));         
           $(this).find(".total span").text(quantity * price);

            sum = 0;

           $(".line-total").each(function(){
           sum = sum + Number($(this).text());
           })   
           return parseInt(value, 10) + 1;

          })
        }

    else {

        $('.panel').append(
            '<div class="container"> '+ 
        '<input type="hidden"  value='+product.id+' data-id="'+product.id+'"   name="product_id[]" />'+
            '<table style="width:100%;" class="table" id="tables">'+
            '<thead>'+
            '<thead>'+
    '<tbody>'+
    '<tr>'+
    '<td  class="name" >'+product.name+'</td>'+
    '<td  class="price" data-price="'+product.price+'">'+product.price+'</td>'+
    '<td><p class="total" ><span class="line-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p></td>'+

    }
```

Comment: How you call the `source` function ? give as a live working example so we could help.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki i call `source` by checking a checkbox.. Live example how  please?

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/